# IF formula to number unique locations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry this is probably very simple but i can not get anything to work.

i have added an image of the criteria cell A being a route ID and column B being a Post code and i need a sequential return based on those 2 values, so the first unique post code shows 1 and the second unique showing a 2 and so on but returning to 1 when the route ID is diffent

[image]

i have tried nested IF's but nothing

Comment: Would consider looking at this with if(), and() etc but data is an image and can't be bothered to type...

Comment: Probably the simplest, In `C2`: `=IF(A2<>A1,1,IF(B2=B1,C1,C1+1))`. Copy down.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then you could try the following as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, UNIQUE(A2:B30),
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     c, SCAN(0,b=DROP(VSTACK("",b),-1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,1))),
     XLOOKUP(A2:A30&"|"&B2:B30,b&"|"&DROP(a,,1),c))
```

---